$\ddot x$ vs. $\dot x^2$
I'm working on a physics assignment and am having some trouble. I need to integrate $r\dot\theta^2$ with respect to $t$. However, my trouble lies in the definition of the upper-dot format.
Given:
$$ \dot\theta=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\theta $$
and
$$ \ddot\theta=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\theta $$
If I square $\dot\theta$, I get:
$$\dot\theta^2 = \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\theta\right)\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\theta\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\theta^2$$
Does this mean that:
$$\dot\theta^2 = \ddot\theta\theta$$
So if I go back to my original task:
$$\int r\dot\theta^2\, \mathrm{d}t \rightarrow \int r\ddot\theta\theta \,\mathrm{d}t$$
Which I still don't really know how to integrate, my first thoughts are a combination of chain rule and integration by parts, any help is appreciated!

No, $\dot \theta^2$ is the square of the first derivative, not the second derivative of $\theta ^2.$


$$\dot\theta^2 = \left(\frac{d}{dt}\theta\right)\left(\frac{d}{dt}\theta\right)=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\theta^2$$

This line assumes that you can interchange operators (the derivative) and functions ($\theta$). This is not the case. The most you can say is that $\dot \theta^2$ is the square of the derivative.
As an example, suppose $\theta(t) = t^2$. Then
$$
\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t} \right)^2
= (2t)^2
= 4t^2
$$
but the result you claim would give
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} (t^2)^2
= \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} t^4
= 12t^2
$$
Definitely not the same thing.
